# Updating FontLoader difficulties

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to update this threejs version r128 to 141 (rest of the animations on page are 0.141) but am struggling to get this code to work. I know for sure there is an issue with how I am importing FontLoader since the change in patch
[132–>133 "FontLoader and Font have been removed from core. Both classes are now located in examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js"](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide)

But the docs page for FontLoader on official ThreeJs website is updated to 0.148 and doesn’t show info on older versions as it is now pointing at /addons/ folder:
[three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/FontLoader)
I know that the FontLoader itself comes from this URL:
/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js

- so I have no idea how to solve this or use FontLoader for 141. I tried many many many many different ways and could not get it to work. I tried local npm install three@0.141 and manually calling the local location of FontLoader into the script and it doesn’t work. Here is the .js, which currently functions under r128:

```
const preload = () => {
    let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onLoad = function () {
      const environment = new Environment(typo, particle);
    };
  
    var typo = null;
    const loader = new THREE.FontLoader(manager);
    const font = loader.load(
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/dydre7amr/raw/upload/v1612950355/font_zsd4dr.json",
      function (font) {
        typo = font;
      }
    );
    const particle = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager).load(
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/dfvtkoboz/image/upload/v1605013866/particle_a64uzf.png"
    );
  };
  
  if (
    document.readyState === "complete" ||
    (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)
  )
    preload();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", preload);
  
  let magicDivInViewport = false; // Track if the magic div is in the viewport
  
  class Environment {
    constructor(font, particle) {
      this.font = font;
      this.particle = particle;
      this.container = document.querySelector("#magic");
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.createCamera();
      this.createRenderer();
      this.setup();
      this.bindEvents();
      this.startTimer();
    }
  
    startTimer() {
      this.mouseEnabled = false;
      this.createParticles.onMouseDown();
      this.createParticles.disableMouseTracking(); // Disable mouse tracking
  
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.createParticles.onMouseUp();
        this.createParticles.enableMouseTracking(); // Enable mouse tracking
        this.mouseEnabled = true;
      }, 6000);
    }
  
    bindEvents() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize.bind(this));
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.checkMagicDivInViewport.bind(this));
    }
  
    checkMagicDivInViewport() {
      const magicDiv = document.querySelector("#magic");
      const rect = magicDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
      magicDivInViewport = rect.top <= window.innerHeight && rect.bottom >= 0;
      
      if (!magicDivInViewport) {
        // Magic div is out of view, stop JavaScript associated with it
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.checkMagicDivInViewport.bind(this));
        // Remove other event listeners and clean up resources as needed
      }
    }
  
    setup() {
      this.createParticles = new CreateParticles(
        this.scene,
        this.font,
        this.particle,
        this.camera,
        this.renderer
      );
    }
  
    render() {
      this.createParticles.render();
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  
    createCamera() {
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        65,
        this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight,
        1,
        10000
      );
      this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    }
  
    createRenderer() {
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      this.renderer.setSize(
        this.container.clientWidth,
        this.container.clientHeight
      );
  
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
  
      this.renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
      this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  
      this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
        this.render();
      });
    }
  
    onWindowResize() {
      this.camera.aspect =
        this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.renderer.setSize(
        this.container.clientWidth,
        this.container.clientHeight
      );
    }
  }
  
  class CreateParticles {
      constructor(scene, font, particleImg, camera, renderer) {
          this.scene = scene;
          this.font = font;
          this.particleImg = particleImg;
          this.camera = camera;
          this.renderer = renderer;
  
          this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
          this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2(-200, 200);
  
          this.colorChange = new THREE.Color();
          this.mouseEnabled = false;  // Initialize as false.
          this.mouseTrackingEnabled = false; // Initialize as false.
  
          this.button = false;
  
          this.data = {
              text: "FUTURE\nIS NOW",
              amount: 1500,
              particleSize: 1,
              particleColor: 0xffffff,
              textSize: 16,
              area: 250,
              ease: 0.05
          };
  
          this.setup();
          this.bindEvents();
      }
  
     bindEvents() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize.bind(this));
  
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.mouseEnabled = true; // Enable after 3 seconds
        this.mouseTrackingEnabled = true; // Enable after 3 seconds
  
        // Attach mouse event listeners after the delay
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp.bind(this));
      }, 6000); // 3 seconds delay
    }
  
  
      disableMouseTracking() {
          this.mouseTrackingEnabled = false;
      }
  
      enableMouseTracking() {
          this.mouseTrackingEnabled = true;
      }
  
  
  
  
  
    setup() {
      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(
        this.visibleWidthAtZDepth(100, this.camera),
        this.visibleHeightAtZDepth(100, this.camera)
      );
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00,
        transparent: true
      });
      this.planeArea = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.planeArea.visible = false;
      this.createText();
    }
  
    bindEvents() {
          this.mouseEnabled = false; // Initially set this to false
  
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.mouseEnabled = true; // Enable after 6 seconds
      }, 6000); // 6000 milliseconds equals 6 seconds
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp.bind(this));
    }
  
      onMouseDown(event) {
      // Check if the event is undefined, which means it's a simulated mouse down
      if (!event) {
        // Simulate mouse down at the center of the window
        this.mouse.x = 0;
        this.mouse.y = 0;
      } else {
        this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      }
  
      const vector = new THREE.Vector3(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 0.5);
      vector.unproject(this.camera);
      const dir = vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize();
      const distance = -this.camera.position.z / dir.z;
      this.currenPosition = this.camera.position
        .clone()
        .add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));
  
      const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
      this.buttom = true;
      this.data.ease = 0.01;
    }
    onMouseUp() {
      this.buttom = false;
      this.data.ease = 0.05;
    }
  
    onMouseMove() {
      this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    }
  
    render(level) {
      const time = ((0.001 * performance.now()) % 12) / 12;
      const zigzagTime = (1 + Math.sin(time * 2 * Math.PI)) / 6;
  
      this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
  
      const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.planeArea);
  
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const pos = this.particles.geometry.attributes.position;
        const copy = this.geometryCopy.attributes.position;
        const coulors = this.particles.geometry.attributes.customColor;
        const size = this.particles.geometry.attributes.size;
  
        const mx = intersects[0].point.x;
        const my = intersects[0].point.y;
        const mz = intersects[0].point.z;
  
        for (var i = 0, l = pos.count; i < l; i++) {
          const initX = copy.getX(i);
          const initY = copy.getY(i);
          const initZ = copy.getZ(i);
  
          let px = pos.getX(i);
          let py = pos.getY(i);
          let pz = pos.getZ(i);
  
          this.colorChange.setHSL(0.5, 1, 1);
          coulors.setXYZ(
            i,
            this.colorChange.r,
            this.colorChange.g,
            this.colorChange.b
          );
          coulors.needsUpdate = true;
  
          size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize;
          size.needsUpdate = true;
  
          let dx = mx - px;
          let dy = my - py;
          const dz = mz - pz;
  
          const mouseDistance = this.distance(mx, my, px, py);
          let d = (dx = mx - px) * dx + (dy = my - py) * dy;
          const f = -this.data.area / d;
  
          if (this.buttom) {
            const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            px -= f * Math.cos(t);
            py -= f * Math.sin(t);
  
            this.colorChange.setHSL(0.5 + zigzagTime, 1.0, 0.5);
            coulors.setXYZ(
              i,
              this.colorChange.r,
              this.colorChange.g,
              this.colorChange.b
            );
            coulors.needsUpdate = true;
  
            if (
              px > initX + 70 ||
              px < initX - 70 ||
              py > initY + 70 ||
              py < initY - 70
            ) {
              this.colorChange.setHSL(0.15, 1.0, 0.5);
              coulors.setXYZ(
                i,
                this.colorChange.r,
                this.colorChange.g,
                this.colorChange.b
              );
              coulors.needsUpdate = true;
            }
          } else {
            if (mouseDistance < this.data.area) {
              if (i % 5 == 0) {
                const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                px -= 0.03 * Math.cos(t);
                py -= 0.03 * Math.sin(t);
  
                this.colorChange.setHSL(0.15, 1.0, 0.5);
                coulors.setXYZ(
                  i,
                  this.colorChange.r,
                  this.colorChange.g,
                  this.colorChange.b
                );
                coulors.needsUpdate = true;
  
                size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize / 1.2;
                size.needsUpdate = true;
              } else {
                const t = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                px += f * Math.cos(t);
                py += f * Math.sin(t);
  
                pos.setXYZ(i, px, py, pz);
                pos.needsUpdate = true;
  
                size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize * 1.3;
                size.needsUpdate = true;
              }
  
              if (
                px > initX + 10 ||
                px < initX - 10 ||
                py > initY + 10 ||
                py < initY - 10
              ) {
                this.colorChange.setHSL(0.15, 1.0, 0.5);
                coulors.setXYZ(
                  i,
                  this.colorChange.r,
                  this.colorChange.g,
                  this.colorChange.b
                );
                coulors.needsUpdate = true;
  
                size.array[i] = this.data.particleSize / 1.8;
                size.needsUpdate = true;
              }
            }
          }
  
          px += (initX - px) * this.data.ease;
          py += (initY - py) * this.data.ease;
          pz += (initZ - pz) * this.data.ease;
  
          pos.setXYZ(i, px, py, pz);
          pos.needsUpdate = true;
        }
      }
    }
  
    createText() {
      let thePoints = [];
  
      let shapes = this.font.generateShapes(this.data.text, this.data.textSize);
      let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shapes);
      geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  
      const xMid =
        -0.5 * (geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x);
      const yMid =
        (geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y) / 2.85;
  
      geometry.center();
  
      let holeShapes = [];
  
      for (let q = 0; q < shapes.length; q++) {
        let shape = shapes[q];
  
        if (shape.holes && shape.holes.length > 0) {
          for (let j = 0; j < shape.holes.length; j++) {
            let hole = shape.holes[j];
            holeShapes.push(hole);
          }
        }
      }
      shapes.push.apply(shapes, holeShapes);
  
      let colors = [];
      let sizes = [];
  
      for (let x = 0; x < shapes.length; x++) {
        let shape = shapes[x];
  
        const amountPoints =
          shape.type == "Path" ? this.data.amount / 2 : this.data.amount;
  
        let points = shape.getSpacedPoints(amountPoints);
  
        points.forEach((element, z) => {
          const a = new THREE.Vector3(element.x, element.y, 0);
          thePoints.push(a);
          colors.push(this.colorChange.r, this.colorChange.g, this.colorChange.b);
          sizes.push(1);
        });
      }
  
      let geoParticles = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(thePoints);
      geoParticles.translate(xMid, yMid, 0);
  
      geoParticles.setAttribute(
        "customColor",
        new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3)
      );
      geoParticles.setAttribute(
        "size",
        new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(sizes, 1)
      );
  
      const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
          color: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
          pointTexture: { value: this.particleImg }
        },
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
  
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest: false,
        transparent: true
      });
  
      this.particles = new THREE.Points(geoParticles, material);
      this.scene.add(this.particles);
  
      this.geometryCopy = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      this.geometryCopy.copy(this.particles.geometry);
    }
  
    visibleHeightAtZDepth(depth, camera) {
      const cameraOffset = camera.position.z;
      if (depth < cameraOffset) depth -= cameraOffset;
      else depth += cameraOffset;
  
      const vFOV = (camera.fov * Math.PI) / 180;
  
      return 2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2) * Math.abs(depth);
    }
  
    visibleWidthAtZDepth(depth, camera) {
      const height = this.visibleHeightAtZDepth(depth, camera);
      return height * camera.aspect;
    }
  
    distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
    }
  }
  // Shaders
const vertexShader = `
attribute float size;
attribute vec3 customColor;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
  vColor = customColor;
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}`;

const fragmentShader = `
uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D pointTexture;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
  gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( pointTexture, gl_PointCoord );
}`;
```

You can see my current functioning code under Threejs version r128 in this CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Maxim-Shlyaptsev/pen/qBLxxRZ

And you can see my current attempt at updating it to version 141:
https://codepen.io/Maxim-Shlyaptsev/pen/poqarBO

And you can see my current attempt at updating it to version 141:
https://codepen.io/Maxim-Shlyaptsev/pen/poqarBO

Comment: The issue has been solved in the `three.js` forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/updating-fontloader-difficulties/56317